# Paste data from dictionary into Excel file

Tags: python-3.x, dictionary, export-to-csv

I have a dictionary containing various products, as follows:

```
my_dict={'name':['n1','n2','n3','n4'], 'size':['s1',',',',','s4], 'compat':[['el11','el12','el13'],['el2'],[','],['el41','el42']]}
```

i would like to paste these datas into an csv file as so :

---

1st column-1st line : name

1st column-2nd line : size

1st column-3rd line : compat

---

2nd column-1st line : n1

2nd column-2nd line : s1

2nd column-3rd line : ['el11','el12','el13']

---

3rd column-1st line : n2

3rd column-2nd line :

3rd column-3rd line : ['el2']

---

etc.

---

In my case (not the example), i have 25 keys and thousand of products referenced.

i tried :

```
import csv
with open('C:\\testexport2.csv', 'wb') as csv_file:
    writer = csv.writer(csv_file)
    for key, value in my_dict.items():
```

... but don't know what to do next. 
Would be awesome if you could help !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use pandas:

```
import pandas as pd

pd.DataFrame(my_dict).T.to_csv("data.csv")
```

now check in your currect directory for data.csv

Comment: thanks @Onyambu
One of my key is description, and i have this kind of text : 

"blablééblé.(linebreak)
oula. ble bête âge."

How can i past it in a single cell with accents and linebreaks ??

Comment: @Madmaxoo what you get from the code has everything in one cell is csv. Expand your csv columns and you will see that

Comment: that's what i did @Onyambu, and it breaks all the file ! 
here is a example of description : "Effet immédiat sur les rides\r\nComble et lisse les rides\r\nUnifie le teint\r\nUne peau rajeunie.\r\nAu toucher la peau est douce, comme veloutée\n"
I would like to delete these \n and \r and to have all the text pasted with accents and if needed linebreaks in one cell ! Hope you can help :)

Comment: @Madmaxoo you will have to edit the output in excel by using regular expressions I guess. maybe split the text and wrap it in excel. You wil have to google that